# Error while Implementing Mesibo Android SDK

Tags: android, mesibo

Currently, I am implementing mesibo API for messaging and video chat and I am following this link https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/first-app/android/ to get started. However, after creating an instance of the mesibo I am not able to access any method like set token, add listener, start, etc. I have tried rebuild, restart, clean but nothing seems to work. It is giving me compile error in all the method after init. It would be really great if anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

```
val mesibo = Mesibo.getInstance()
mesibo.init(this)
mesibo.addListener(this)
mesibo.setAccessToken("user_token")
mesibo.start()
```

Gradle

```
implementation 'com.mesibo.api:mesibo:1.0.90'
implementation 'com.mesibo.api:ui:1.1.32'
implementation 'com.mesibo.api:calls:1.0.75'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, note the case.

```
Mesibo.init(this)
Mesibo.addListener(this)
Mesibo.setAccessToken("user_token")
Mesibo.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

SDK is okay but you need to follow given step:

```
Mesibo.init(this)
Mesibo.addListener(this)
Mesibo.setAccessToken("user_token")
Mesibo.start()
```